# What can I do if I need the request.user object in a middleware but get the user from JwtAuthGuard?

Tags: typescript, authentication, jwt, nestjs

I'm creating a middleware to get a member entity and attach it to the request object, to do so I need the userId of the user object obtained from JwtAuthGuard, but the guards are executed after middlewares.

I was thinking of creating an interceptor instead of a middleware to do it or create the authentication as a middleware.

This is the middleware I'm creating:

```
@Injectable()
export class SpaceMemberMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  constructor(private readonly membersService: MembersService) {}

  async use(req: any, res: any, next: () => void) {
    const user: User = req.user;

    const member: Member = await this.membersService.findByUserId(user.userId);
    if (!member) throw new BadRequestException();

    req.member = member;

    next();
  }
}
```

My AuthGuard:

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {
    super();
  }

  canActivate(
    context: ExecutionContext,
  ): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    const isPublic = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride<boolean>(IS_PUBLIC_KEY, [
      context.getHandler(),
      context.getClass(),
    ]);

    return isPublic || super.canActivate(context);
  }
}
```

And my Strategy:

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: { username: string }): Promise<User> {
    const user: User = await this.usersService.findOneByCognitoId(
      payload.username,
    );

    if (!user) throw new UnauthorizedException();

    return user;
  }
}
```

What should I do? All recommendations are accepted. And I'm sorry, my English is bad. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Interceptors are triggered after the Middlewares (according to the [NestJS docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/request-lifecycle#summary)). As you mentioned, it may be a good idea to use an [Interceptor](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors) for your case.

Something like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class SpaceMemberInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  public intercept(context: ExecutionContext, handler: CallHandler): Observable<unknown> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const user: User = request.user; // the authorised user should be present

    const member: Member = await this.membersService.findByUserId(user.userId);
    if (!member) throw new BadRequestException();
    
    request.member = member
    
    return handler.handle();
  }
}
```

Than you just have to set up the interceptor:

```
@UseInterceptors(new SpaceMemberInterceptor())
export class CatsController {}
```

You also can configure the interceptor at the global or route level, depending on your needs ([see docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors#binding-interceptors))